# Python PC to Arduino Serial Communication

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I am very new to both Python and Arduino. If you need any more info just tell me.

What i want to do:
I would like to control a few servos with the arduino. I want to change the angles of the Servos in a GUI on the PC(later RPi) and send them via Serial Communication to the Arduino

My Arduino Code looks like this:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

int angle;
int pinServo1 = 5;
Servo servo1;       
int min = 0.547;    
int max = 2.47;     

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(pinServo1,OUTPUT);   
   servo1.attach(pinServo1,min,max);        
}

void loop()
{
   if(Serial.available() > 0)
      {
        Serial.read();
        angle = Serial.parseInt();
        servo1.write(angle);
      }
}
```

So far no errors with that.

Problem seems to be my Python code:

```
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial(8,9600)

while 1:
    print ("Enter new angle:")
    string = input()
    angle = str(string)
    arduino.write(angle)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Transmission successful!")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Enter new angle:
90
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yoogibubu/Desktop/STUDIUM/BACHELORARBEIT/GUI/send.py", line 10, in <module>
    arduino.write(angle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 283, in write
data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 76, in to_bytes
    b.append(item)  # this one handles int and str for our emulation and ints for Python 3.x
TypeError: an integer is required
>>>
```

If i try to parse my input into an integer i get another error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: i'm using python 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

serial.write expects a byte array data type argument. For sending strings, they have to be converted to a byte array first, especially in Python3.x as strings are stored using Unicode making things more elaborate that a simple array of chars.

Try the following:

```
arduino.write(angle.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly write this `loop()`:

```
void loop()
{
   if(Serial.available() > 0)
      {
        angle = Serial.read();
        servo1.write(angle);
      }
}
```

But the issue is with `servo1.attach()`. Your servo `min` and `max` are expected to be `int` values for min and max pulsewith in us (not ms). This is used to map the reading result.

You probably want to have something like:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

int angle;
int pinServo1 = 5;
Servo servo1;       
int min = 547; //in us - BTW 1000 would be safer but servo has less range    
int max = 2470;  //in us - BTW 2000 would be safer  

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(pinServo1, OUTPUT);   
   servo1.attach(pinServo1, min, max);        
}

void loop()
{
   if(Serial.available() > 0)
      {
        angle = Serial.read();
        servo1.write(angle);
      }
}
```